# Homebrew uses Xcode Git instead of $(which git)

Tags: macos, homebrew

My Xcode Git (`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git`) is non-executable (`-rw-r--r--`), I think because I `chmod`ed it a long time ago so I wouldn't have to worry about it falling out of date.

Even though my Homebrew-installed version of Git, `/usr/local/bin/git`, which works fine, is what shows up for `which git`, and even though `brew config` outputs that it's using `/usr/bin/local/git` (`Git: 2.16.0 => /usr/local/bin/git`), when I run any Homebrew command that involves Git, I get the error:

```
git: error: can't exec '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git' (errno=Permission denied)
```

So it seems that despite what `brew config` says, Homebrew is trying to use `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git` or `/usr/bin/git` (which seems to somehow point to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git`, as I get the same error as above when I try to run it, although it is not a symlink and has a different inode number).

Setting `chmod +x` on `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git` makes everything work, but I don't see why I should have to do that. Replacing `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git` with a symlink to `/usr/local/bin/git` does not work, I get an error saying Git wasn't found at that path.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove XCode Git if you no longer need it ...

Comment: I've tried that, and it doesn't fix this problem. Homebrew still tries to call Xcode Git.

Comment: Then reinstall homebrew.

Comment: Tried that, it did not fix the problem. I got the same error when reinstalling.

Comment: Do you have other relevant environment variables defined?

Comment: What environment variables could be relevant here?

Comment: `PATH` is defined to put `/usr/local/bin/git` first, but not aware that Homebrew relies on other environment variables to set the location of the Git binary it uses.